# check if array exists in php mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

how to check if the array exists in php.

I ve the array called $contact["categories"] in some of the rows in mongodb collection.
some rows doesn't have that array. how to check if particular array exists in collection??

Comment: Read about `$exists` operator

Comment: Do you want to check only if array exists, or if it exists and holds certain elements?

Comment: just check only if the array exists?? does $exist work on arrays as well?? when i try to use $contact["categories"], since it doesnt exits it is throwing error as undefined index.

Comment: An "undefined index" _warning_ is telling you that just that one array element does not exist, not necessarily the entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the index existence like this:

```
 if (isset($contact["categories"])) {

    }
```

OR

[array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if( array_key_exists('categories', $contact) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use $exists parameter to check whether element exists or not.

```
array('array_name' => array('$exists' => true))
```